# iTerm2: Stopping the inactive pane from dimming

Tags: iterm, iterm2

I'm using irssi in one pane and [nicklist.pl](http://wouter.coekaerts.be/irssi/nicklist) in the other, and whenever I'm in the irssi pane, the nicklist pane is dimmed:

[image]

How do I stop the inactive pane from dimming?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

On newer versions of iTerm2 (Build 3.3.2+ for me), unchecking the following setting solved this:

> Preferences(⌘,) -> Appearance -> Dimming

Then uncheck the first option:

> "Dim inactive split panes"

[image]

Comment: Have changed the accepted answer to this one instead of my one :)

Comment: I have had an irrational annoyance, perhaps somewhat anxious feeling, when using split panes because of this feature being enabled. Thank you!

Answer (score 167):

Found it! There is a setting in Settings -> Appearance -> Dim inactive split panes. I would have quite liked to be able to set it for just the two profiles, but it doesn't matter that much.

[image]

Comment: This "feature" was so annoying